# Default risk and stock price probability distributions

Tags: equities, probability, default, default-risk

First of all, I realise this question might border on `meta-finance', so I'd be totally OK if it gets closed.

Having said that, the question itself:

Given a stock $S$, in the absence of default it is quite clear that the probability the stock price at time $T$ takes values in $(0,\infty)$ is $1$ for all $T$.

In the presence of default, however, the price at $T$ isn't even defined if the company defaulted at $t<T$. Can we express this mathematically as $P(0<S_T < \infty) = f(T) \leq 1$?

To illustrate what I mean with a simple example, consider the probability density of the stock price (zero interest rate and dividend yield for now) given by
$$
q(S_T,T | S_t,t) = e^{-c(T,t)} p(S_T,T | S_t,t)
$$
where $p$ is the usual lognormal density with constant volatility $\sigma$ and $c(t,T)$ is a positive deterministic function of $t$ and $T$. In this simple example let's assume that we only observe a term structure of IVs and no skew/smile.

Then,
$$
E\left[(S_T-K)_+ \right] = e^{-c(T,t)} C^{BS} (S_t,K,\sigma,T)
$$
We can calibrate $c(t,T)$ to the IV TS through
$$
C^{BS} (S_t,K,IV(T),T) = e^{-c(T,t)} C^{BS} (S_t,K,\sigma,T)
$$

I am working on generalising this to stochastic $c$ and/or a local $c$ to get skew/smile.

Comment: We express this usually as $S_T=0$ when $T$ is on or after the time of default. This defines $S_T$ for all $T$.

Comment: @KurtG. Yes that's the usual definition / interpretation. I am trying to look at it another way. See my edit, I saw your comment after my edit.

Comment: Besides, $S_T = 0$ isn't even an allowed value in many models. It doesn't make sense. It's like saying the empty set is zero. It isn't.

Comment: If I get this correcty, you are looking for the density of a defaultable stock price process? Isn't that something like $p(S_T=0)+(1-p(S_T=0))q(S_T)$, with $q$ the density under no-default?

Comment: @Kermittfrog I see two close votes under the reason of 'basic question' (I was hoping at least for off-topic :)), but the `basic question' I have is: if the price of a stock is the result of measurement (i.e. trading, or at the very least bid-ask), it's easy to say its price is zero after it has defaulted, been de-listed, migrated to a parallel universe, but how about thinking about it as that its probability of having a price is not 1 anymore (since it could happen that at $T$ the stock just doesn't exist anymore), what happens then? That's the gist of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I am still trying to understand your (intersting) question - No close votes from me, tho.

Comment: @Kermittfrog So saying the probability that a price at $T$ is somewhere between $0$ and $\infty$ is equal to 1, is saying that the stock price is somewhere for sure, it is measurable, it is 'alive'. Saying that the probability that it's alive (measurable) is say 0.9, then that means that the probability it's dead (not measurable) is 0.1. Indeed, when a stock is delisted, due to default for instance, it's not measurable anymore. There are jump and jump to default models that explain the skew. But the admittedly philosophical problem I have with these is that the price continues to be measurable

Comment: Too long, continued: I am trying to turn this 'philosophical problem' into something concrete.

Comment: @Frido . "$S_T=0$ isn't even allowed in many models." LoL. What should a stock be worth if the company was wiped out ? See also this example of a [jump-to-default model](http://www2.math.uu.se/~johant/jumptodefault.pdf).

Comment: @KurtG. Why the 'LoL'? If you read my comments above I specifically mentioned jump to default. Obviously I mean diffusion models.

Comment: Never mind. That comment of yours could have been clearer. A paper worth reading is mentioned in [this QSE post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59186/how-option-value-default-adjusted-in-jump-diffusion-model). Reading your other comments I don't get what it means when the stock price is 'alive' after it has defaulted.

Comment: @KurtG. Where exactly do I say it's alive *after* it has defaulted?

Comment: Maybe you want to edit your question and incorporate all the clarifications in the comments?

Comment: @DimitriVulis No it's fine, I am still searching where I wrote something is alive after it's dead. Other than that I'm done.